# Validation loss extremely high with good accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, loss-functions

I have tried creating a CNN for the famous MNIST challenge, but while I achive good accuracy on the validation set during training (I have around 99% after 20 epochs), the validation loss is behaving oddly: the loss is pretty normal (it goes down smoothly), but validation loss seems to be random values.
Also, while I know accuracy on the test set should be lower than on the validation set, it goes from 99% to 96%. Any idea why these things are happening? I suppose I've written something poorly in my code, because that doesn't seem like a normal behavior. Here is what I wrote:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


mnist=keras.datasets.mnist
(X,y),(X_test,y_test)=mnist.load_data()

X_valid,X_train=X[:5000]/255.0,X[5000:]/255.0
y_valid,y_train=y[:5000],y[5000:]
X_mean=X_train.mean(axis=0,keepdims=True)
X_std=X_train.std(axis=0,keepdims=True)+1e-7
X_train=(X_train-X_mean)/X_std
X_test=(X_test-X_mean)/X_std
X_valid=(X_valid-X_mean)/X_std

X_train=X_train[...,np.newaxis] 
X_valid=X_valid[...,np.newaxis]  
X_test=X_test[...,np.newaxis]  

model=keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,3,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,3,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(128,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(10,activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer="nadam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=20,validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid))

pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

Here is what I obtained after executing the code:

Train on 55000 samples, validate on 5000 samples

```
Epoch 1/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 136us/sample - loss: 0.1904 - accuracy: 0.9442 - val_loss: 5.0653 - val_accuracy: 0.9834

Epoch 2/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0799 - accuracy: 0.9761 - val_loss: 1.9537 - val_accuracy: 0.9880

Epoch 3/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0598 - accuracy: 0.9823 - val_loss: 5.4052 - val_accuracy: 0.9864

Epoch 4/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 126us/sample - loss: 0.0530 - accuracy: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.5642 - val_accuracy: 0.9888

Epoch 5/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 122us/sample - loss: 0.0423 - accuracy: 0.9866 - val_loss: 10.1840 - val_accuracy: 0.9916

Epoch 6/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 122us/sample - loss: 0.0375 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 15.6639 - val_accuracy: 0.9902

Epoch 7/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 121us/sample - loss: 0.0334 - accuracy: 0.9895 - val_loss: 7.7230 - val_accuracy: 0.9892

Epoch 8/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 121us/sample - loss: 0.0312 - accuracy: 0.9905 - val_loss: 40.1243 - val_accuracy: 0.9892

Epoch 9/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0287 - accuracy: 0.9909 - val_loss: 0.0332 - val_accuracy: 0.9904

Epoch 10/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 123us/sample - loss: 0.0253 - accuracy: 0.9923 - val_loss: 14.4594 - val_accuracy: 0.9920

Epoch 11/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 126us/sample - loss: 0.0241 - accuracy: 0.9926 - val_loss: 9.4999 - val_accuracy: 0.9888

Epoch 12/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0239 - accuracy: 0.9928 - val_loss: 0.0350 - val_accuracy: 0.9928

Epoch 13/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 126us/sample - loss: 0.0210 - accuracy: 0.9932 - val_loss: 1.8624 - val_accuracy: 0.9906

Epoch 14/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 122us/sample - loss: 0.0227 - accuracy: 0.9936 - val_loss: 23.4051 - val_accuracy: 0.9918

Epoch 15/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 119us/sample - loss: 0.0227 - accuracy: 0.9933 - val_loss: 18.1206 - val_accuracy: 0.9924

Epoch 16/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0202 - accuracy: 0.9938 - val_loss: 23.3301 - val_accuracy: 0.9910

Epoch 17/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 126us/sample - loss: 0.0173 - accuracy: 0.9944 - val_loss: 0.0534 - val_accuracy: 0.9902

Epoch 18/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 125us/sample - loss: 0.0175 - accuracy: 0.9946 - val_loss: 7.3290 - val_accuracy: 0.9906

Epoch 19/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 127us/sample - loss: 0.0179 - accuracy: 0.9942 - val_loss: 67.2724 - val_accuracy: 0.9904

Epoch 20/20

55000/55000 [==============================] - 7s 126us/sample - loss: 0.0186 - accuracy: 0.9946 - val_loss: 73.3262 - val_accuracy: 0.9892
```

As for the evaluation on the test set:

```
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 46us/sample - loss: 31.8384 - accuracy: 0.9668
```

Here's the image of the loss/accuracy over the epochs:
[image]

Any idea what's happening there? Did I make a beginner's mistake or is this a bug?

Comment: Is each observation of shape 28 x 28 x 1?

Comment: Yes, they are: after constraining the first layer to only accept inputs of the shape input_shape=[28,28,1], there has been no error, meaning they all have the right shape.